# Docker logs not displayed in the mounted log file

Tags: docker, logging, amazon-ec2, circleci, docker-logs

We are having some services running in docker containers on an EC2 machine (Linux based).
These containers are deployed using CircleCI.

Following is the circle CI config.yml

```yaml
version: 2
jobs:
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: docker:18.06.0-ce-git
    working_directory: ~/app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Install awscli
          command: |
            apk add --no-cache py-pip
            pip install awscli==1.15.72
      - run:
          name: Build Docker image
          command: |
            docker build -t resource-etl .
      - run:
          name: Push image to ECR
          command: |
            eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_REGION)
            docker tag ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:latest ${ECR_REPOSITORY_BASE_URI}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:latest
            docker push ${ECR_REPOSITORY_BASE_URI}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:latest
      - run:
          name: Deploy container to EC2
          command: |
            sh .circleci/deploy.sh
workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy
          # filters:
          #   branches:
          #     only: master
```

Following is the deploy.sh script that configures the log path. The logs need to be stored in a folder /vol/log/{service-name}/{service-name}.log on the EC2 instance.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
LOG_PATH="/vol/log/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}"

ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ${EC2_USERNAME}@${EC2_HOST} << EOF
    # setup logs
    sudo mkdir -p ${LOG_PATH}
    sudo chmod 777 ${LOG_PATH}

    # login and pull image from ECR
    eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_REGION)
    docker pull ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:latest

    # remove old container by name
    docker ps -a -q -f name=${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME} | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm -f

    docker run \
        --detach \
        -e AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" \
        -e AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" \
        -e AWS_SQS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${AWS_SQS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" \
        -e AWS_SQS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${AWS_SQS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" \
        -e AWS_SQS_REGION="${AWS_SQS_REGION}" \
        -e AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME="${AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME}" \
        -e SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL="${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}" \
        -e SLACK_SERVICE_NAME="${SLACK_SERVICE_NAME}" \
        -e TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL="${TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL}" \
        -e TEAMS_SERVICE_NAME="${TEAMS_SERVICE_NAME}" \
        -e RDB_API_URL="${RDB_API_URL}" \
        -e CASSANDRA_API_URL="${CASSANDRA_API_URL}" \
        -e ENVIRONMENT="${ENVIRONMENT}" \
        -e TO_BE_PROCESSED_PREFIX="${TO_BE_PROCESSED_PREFIX}" \
        -e PROCESSED_PREFIX="${PROCESSED_PREFIX}" \
        -e REQUIRES_ATTENTION_PREFIX="${REQUIRES_ATTENTION_PREFIX}" \
        -e GENERATED_JSON_PREFIX="${GENERATED_JSON_PREFIX}" \
        -v ${LOG_PATH}:/app/log \
        --log-driver none \
        --name ${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME} \
        ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}:latest

    # delete dangling images
    docker images -q -f dangling=true | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
    # delete dangling volumes
    docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker volume rm
EOF
```

These are all python services and we use the logging module to add logs throughout the code.
The environment variables used in the above `deploy.sh` file are all set in the Circle CI environment variables.

On checking the container configuration using docker inspect,
I see that the `LogPath` is empty. However, the `LogPath` is being configured by the script above. These exact same files had been working before and we could see all the logs by doing:

```bash
cat /vol/log/{service-name}/{service-name}.log
```

I don't know what has changed suddenly and we are unable to see any logs.

I am not very familiar docker, so I would really appreciate some help on this.

I have tried removing the flag, `--log-driver none` from the `deploy.sh` script. This way logs are being displayed using the docker logs command but not in the log file.

Comment: Did you tried `ssh` into the EC2 machine and checked?

Comment: Yes, the log files in the mounted folder have no logs.